# Can I override a less-css function based on a class?

Tags: css, less

For example my `html` tag has the class `ie9`. I want to define a default function and override its definition when the `ie9` class exists:

```
.word-break(){
    word-break: break-word;
}

.ie9 {
    .word-break(){
        word-break: break-all;
    }
}


div > p {
    .word-break();
}
```

This however does not work as intended. Nothing happens in IE9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the selector inside the mixin:

```
.word-break() {
    .ie9 & {
        word-break: break-all;
    }
}
```

The `&` represents the selector you're invoking the mixin inside of.

If you simply write `.ie9 {`, it will generate `div > p .ie9`, which is probably not what you want.
Putting the `&` last moves the original selector later.

Comment: I was about to try something with [Guarded Mixins](http://lesscss.org/#-pattern-matching-and-guard-expressions), but I'm not sure it's possible. Your answer is way better.